# Rekonq crashes on Ubuntu 12.04. Cant display some images?

Tags: rekonq

Here is the crash information. This started happenning after I tried update Rekonq to 2.0 version. But now I have downgraded to 0.9

[Here](http://handytutorial.com/install-rekonq-2-0-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/) is the guide which I have followed - http://handytutorial.com/install-rekonq-2-0-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/

```
Application: rekonq (rekonq), signal: Segmentation fault
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0xb2d95980 (LWP 15340))]

Thread 9 (Thread 0xb079bb40 (LWP 15341)):
#0  0xb7792424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb756d5f0 in poll () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb39d2a7b in g_poll () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0xb39c50ae in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0xb39c556b in g_main_loop_run () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0xb1653134 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
#6  0xb39e86b3 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#7  0xb3d42d4c in start_thread () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#8  0xb757bd3e in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 8 (Thread 0xafdffb40 (LWP 15342)):
#0  0xb7792424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb756d5f0 in poll () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb39d2a7b in g_poll () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0xb39c50ae in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0xb39c556b in g_main_loop_run () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0xb154f1ba in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#6  0xb39e86b3 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#7  0xb3d42d4c in start_thread () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#8  0xb757bd3e in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 7 (Thread 0xaf3ffb40 (LWP 15343)):
#0  0xb7792424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb3d46d13 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#2  0xb75896a4 in pthread_cond_timedwait () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0xb3a048e0 in g_cond_wait_until () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0xb39980b9 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0xb39988de in g_async_queue_timeout_pop () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0xb39e8f7c in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#7  0xb39e86b3 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#8  0xb3d42d4c in start_thread () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#9  0xb757bd3e in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 6 (Thread 0x9f534b40 (LWP 15344)):
#0  0xb7792424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb3d4696b in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#2  0xb758964c in pthread_cond_wait () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0xb6acb263 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4
#4  0xb6acb37f in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4
#5  0xb3d42d4c in start_thread () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#6  0xb757bd3e in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 5 (Thread 0x9ed33b40 (LWP 15346)):
#0  0xb7792424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb756d5f0 in poll () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb39d2a7b in g_poll () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0xb39c50ae in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0xb39c5201 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0xb4018887 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#6  0xb3fe450d in QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#7  0xb3fe47a9 in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#8  0xb3ecd94c in QThread::exec() () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#9  0xb3ecda3b in QThread::run() () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#10 0xb3ed0de0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#11 0xb3d42d4c in start_thread () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#12 0xb757bd3e in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 4 (Thread 0x93e3ab40 (LWP 15347)):
#0  0xb7792424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb3d4696b in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#2  0xb758964c in pthread_cond_wait () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0xb737c029 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtScript.so.4
#4  0xb737c06f in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtScript.so.4
#5  0xb3d42d4c in start_thread () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#6  0xb757bd3e in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 3 (Thread 0x93639b40 (LWP 15348)):
#0  0xb7792424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7574d61 in select () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb3fbfe26 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#3  0xb3ed0de0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#4  0xb3d42d4c in start_thread () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#5  0xb757bd3e in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 2 (Thread 0x92cf3b40 (LWP 15352)):
#0  0xb7792424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb3d4696b in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#2  0xb758964c in pthread_cond_wait () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0xb3ed1350 in QWaitCondition::wait(QMutex*, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#4  0xb513cacc in ?? () from /usr/lib/libthreadweaver.so.4
#5  0xb513f95b in ?? () from /usr/lib/libthreadweaver.so.4
#6  0xb513c63a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libthreadweaver.so.4
#7  0xb513fa5c in ?? () from /usr/lib/libthreadweaver.so.4
#8  0xb513c533 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libthreadweaver.so.4
#9  0xb513e4e4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libthreadweaver.so.4
#10 0xb513e59a in ThreadWeaver::Thread::run() () from /usr/lib/libthreadweaver.so.4
#11 0xb3ed0de0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#12 0xb3d42d4c in start_thread () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#13 0xb757bd3e in clone () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0xb2d95980 (LWP 15340)):
[KCrash Handler]
#7  0xb4141dd8 in QObject::staticMetaObject () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#8  0xb37ec4e9 in Attica::ProviderManager::ProviderManager(QFlags<Attica::ProviderManager::ProviderFlag> const&) () from /usr/lib/libattica.so.0.4
#9  0xb55954b2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5
#10 0xb559135a in KAboutApplicationDialog::Private::init(KAboutData const*, QFlags<KAboutApplicationDialog::Option>) () from /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5
#11 0xb5591fff in KAboutApplicationDialog::KAboutApplicationDialog(KAboutData const*, QWidget*) () from /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5
#12 0xb56fa877 in KHelpMenu::aboutApplication() () from /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5
#13 0xb56fa935 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5
#14 0xb3ffc6b1 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#15 0xb42799bd in QAction::triggered(bool) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#16 0xb4279c5b in QAction::activate(QAction::ActionEvent) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#17 0xb4279fb8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#18 0xb3ff7c01 in QMetaCallEvent::placeMetaCall(QObject*) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#19 0xb4000c7b in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#20 0xb4279d31 in QAction::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#21 0xb552e17f in KAction::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5
#22 0xb4280ed4 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#23 0xb428630d in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#24 0xb56349a1 in KApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5
#25 0xb3fe597e in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#26 0xb3fe9ad8 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#27 0xb3fe9e0c in QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#28 0xb4018494 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#29 0xb39c4d86 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#30 0xb39c5125 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#31 0xb39c5201 in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#32 0xb4018887 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#33 0xb4339aaa in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#34 0xb3fe450d in QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#35 0xb3fe47a9 in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#36 0xb3fe9eba in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#37 0xb427ea74 in QApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#38 0xb775be7f in kdemain () from /usr/lib/kde4/libkdeinit/libkdeinit4_rekonq.so
#39 0x080484fb in ?? ()
#40 0xb74a64d3 in __libc_start_main () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#41 0x08048521 in _start ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Synaptic Package Manager. Click on "Reload".Then, "Mark all Upgrades". Then apply.
This will download all the updates from the kubuntu ppa and install them. After update everything will work fine.